# AWSのEC2で作成したサーバのセキュリティ対策に使用できるサービスは何があるでしょうか

Tags: aws, security

■保有知識
・AWSはネットで調べただけで実際の構築経験は無し
・セキュリティに関する設計、構築は未経験

■質問
AWSを使用します。
EC2サーバーを1台構築し、オンプレミスの社内サーバーと接続します。
業務アプリの評価用の環境なので、最小構成での構築とするつもりです。
（VPC内にEC2サーバーを1台構築し、EBSとS3を使用。自社環境のルーターとインターネットVPNで接続。）

これだけであれば良かったのですが、EC2サーバーにiPadからアクセスしたいという要望が出ました。
そうなると外部からのアクセスが発生するのでAWSのWAFサービスを利用しようと考えました。

ところが、WAFはCDNとロードバランサー(ALB)とAPI Gatewayの3カ所にしか設置できないことがわかりました。

1台構成なのでロードバランサーは使いませんし、業務の特性上そこまでアクセス数が多いものでもありません。

この場合、WAFの代わりに使うべきAWSのサービスはありますでしょうか。
EC2の「アクセスコントロール」および「ネットワークACL」という機能がいわゆるFWとのことなので、これを使えばいいのでしょうか。
ただ、iPadからのアクセスをイメージすると、IPがグローバルIPで体系がバラバラだと思うので、この機能で制限できるのか疑問に感じています。

■補足
厳密に「こんなセキュリティ対策をしたい」という要件は出ていません。
あくまで業務アプリの評価環境なので、言ってしまえば、何かしら「セキュリティ対策を意識している」というポーズを見せられればいいと思っています。

そこでAWSのサービスを調べたところWAFが見つかったのですが上述のように設置場所の制限があることがわかり、今回のようなロードバランサなどを必要としない構成の場合はどのようなセキュリティ対策が取れるのだろうかと質問させていただいた次第です。

Comment: 具体的なセキュリティ要件は何でしょうか？WAFとFWとではレイヤも違いますし、できることも変わってきます。今の「セキュリティ対策」ぐらいの質問ですとざっくりしすぎていて、回答が付きづらい印象があります。

Comment: 現在のAWS・オンプレとの「最小構成での構築」はどのような環境になっていますでしょうか？それにより追加の構成が必要か変わってくるかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
質問を修正致しました。

Comment: 過去の質問について、解決したものは解決済みとしてください。未解決のものは尋ねたい内容が明確になるよう補足加筆してください。

Comment: >sayuriさん
すみませんが解決済みはどのようにするのでしょうか。

Comment: iPadにClientVPNを導入して接続する方法は駄目でしょうか？

Comment: (他の質問が)回答によって解決した場合には、以下のヘルプを参考にして下さい。 - [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: iPadは社内環境からのアクセスではないということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、社外からのアクセスも想定しています

Comment: ALBを使ってはいけない理由がないのなら、普通にALBを追加してWAFを利用すればいいのにではと思いました。EC2が１台でも ALBは使えますし、問題ない気がします。